# TextField shouldChangeText property wiring

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I'm using Xcode 13 and SwiftUI (latest version).

I have a simple `TextField` inside of a `View`.

```swift
TextField("enter barcode", value: $scannedBarcode, shouldChangeText : ?)
```

I cannot figure out how to use the `shouldChangeText` property of `TextField`.
I need an example of how to wire up this function.
I'm a newbie to SwiftUI, cannot find an example, and the developer docs are sorely lacking.

Apparently it looks like this maybe:

```swift
shouldChangeText(in: \<UITextRange\>, replacementText: \<String\>)
```

I'm very new to Xcode (a few weeks) and need a solid example of how to use this to filter out all of the non-whole numbers from a text field (no decimal point or alpha characters)

With help below I found this:

```swift
TextField("enter barcode", text: Binding(get: {scannedBarcode}, set: { scannedBarcode = String($0).replacingOccurrences( of:"[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)}))
```

Which is great at filtering out non-digits going into the scannedBarcode variable.  How can I prevent them from hitting the screen in the first place?

Comment: There is no such property in SwiftUI.TextField, you probably wanted UIKit.UITextFielf.

Answer (score 0):

That is really simple in `SwiftUI`, you just have to use `.onChange`. Add this anywhere in your `View`:

```
.onChange(of: scannedBarcode) { newValue in
    //do anything with newValue
}
```

It will give you the exact value of what's in the `TextField`.

For the `UIKit` one, it's the following function which is part of `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
}
```

`UIKit` with `SwiftUI`:

```
struct UTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    let placeHolder: String
    @Binding var text: String?
    init(_ placeHolder: String, text: Binding<String?>) {
        self.placeHolder = placeHolder
        self._text = text
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.placeholder = placeHolder
        return textField
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        text = uiView.text
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            //do something
            //whenever you don't want the text to be entered you return false
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Usage: `UTextField("", text: $someText)`

Comment: Can the .onChange be used to filter out non-numeric values?   Or maybe even stop them from being entered in the first place?

Comment: Well you could use the answer above it's workin gperfectly, but if you really need it to, you can use the `UIKIt TextField`. Updated my answer!

Answer (score -1):

```swift
struct TextFieldPOC: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Test Field", text: $text)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .frame(height: 50)
            .background(content: {
                Rectangle()
                    .stroke(style: .init(lineWidth: 2))
            })
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
            .onChange(of: text) { (first, second) in
                let oldText = first
                let newText = second
                let allowed = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.union(CharacterSet.whitespaces)
                let entered = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: newText)
                if entered.isSubset(of: allowed) == false {
                    text = oldText
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. A good answer explains what was wrong in the question and it explains how the answer solves the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).